# How to update the labels of ColorRampItem automatically after changing ColorRampType to Discrete using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, color-ramp

I want to change the appearance of a mesh layer in QGIS 3.22.

If I change the ColorRampType to Discrete, I can see the change in the legend, but at the labels there are only simple numbers, like "20, 40, 60". If I change in the GUI from "Interpolated" to "Discrete", then I get ranges like "<=20, 20-40, 40-60" and so on.

How can I update the labels of ColorRampItem without creating a whole new ColorRampItemList? (I don't want to generate and set the label, value and color of each item - I want to use the automatic generation like in the GUI.)

Here is the part of my code:

```
i=1

mynewlayer = existing_meshlayer.clone()

mymesh_settings = mynewlayer.rendererSettings()

myMeshRendererScalarSettings = mymesh_settings.scalarSettings(i)
myColorRampShader = myMeshRendererScalarSettings.colorRampShader()

myStyle = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = myStyle.colorRampNames()
ramp = myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[0])

myColorRampShader.setSourceColorRamp(ramp)
myColorRampShader.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Discrete)
myColorRampShader.setClassificationMode(QgsColorRampShader.ClassificationMode.EqualInterval)
myColorRampShader.classifyColorRamp(5)

myMeshRendererScalarSettings.setColorRampShader(myColorRampShader)

mynewlayer.setRendererSettings(mymesh_settings)
mynewlayer.triggerRepaint()
mynewlayer.trigger3DUpdate()
```

And a simple screenshot to illustrate the difference:
[image: screenshot with labels]